# React-widgets DateTimePicker throwing error 'Cannot read property 'oneOfType' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-widgets

I am using redux-forms and their example has a date time picker from react-widgets.  [Redux-Form react-widgets example](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/examples/react-widgets/)

On the example on this page, it has a link to react-widgets. I pretty much followed the example on redux-forms site and I keep getting the following error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'oneOfType' of undefined
./node_modules/react-widgets/lib/util/localizers.js
/node_modules/react-widgets/lib/util/localizers.js:23**

Before anyone asks if Redux-Forms is setup correctly, I have this working with a couple of other render fields, I'm trying to add a date picker and it just crapped out on me.

```
// RenderDateTimePicker.jsx
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import DateTimePicker from 'react-widgets/lib/DateTimePicker';
import moment from 'moment';
import momentLocaliser from 'react-widgets/lib/localizers/moment';
momentLocaliser(moment);

const RenderDateTimePicker = ({input: { onChange, value, name }, label, outercss, inputcss, showTime}) => {

    return (
        <div className={outercss}>
            <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
            <DateTimePicker onChange={onChange}
                            className={inputcss}
                            format={{ raw: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
                            defaultValue={new Date()}
                            time={showTime}
                            value={!value ? null : new DateTimePicker(value)}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
export default RenderDateTimePicker


// Snippet of main compoent
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm  } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import RenderTextField from '../common/RenderTextField';
import RenderDateTimeField from '../common/RenderDateTimePicker';

export class SearchBar extends Component {


    render() {
      const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

        return (
           <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
             <Field  name="startDt"
                     outercss="col-md-2"
                     inputcss="form-control form-control-sm"
                     label="Start Date"
                     component={RenderTextField}
            />

            <Field  name="endDt"
                    outercss="col-md-2"
                    inputcss="form-control form-control-sm"
                    label="End Date"
                    component={RenderDateTimeField}
            />

            <button className="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
      </form>


        )
    }
}
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'SerchAppDeploymentForm'
})(
        connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar)
);
```

Comment: It sounds like a missing `prop-types` import somewhere.

Comment: I saw a solution that said to add that, that didn't work either

Comment: `PropTypes.oneOfType` is a prop validator for react. It's possible that theres some react version mismatching happening--`PropTypes` used to be part of `React` (`React.PropTypes`). So if you're using something that still expects that, you would get that error.

Comment: In the Redux-Form example they are not using PropTypes, so not sure why this would expect it.

Comment: Apparently my work has a very restricted npm repository, the latest version of react-widgets is 3.4.5, which appears to be incompatible with the version of React/Redux we're using.  I tried this at home with version 3.5.0 and it worked.

Comment: Oh wow! Well, I'm glad you at least found and answer as to why it was happening.

Comment: My recommendation for all the react developers, don't work at a bank.... 